# Stoichiometric reaction of hydrochloric acid, potassium nitrate, and copper

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry

I have the following reaction involving these elements:

- $\ce{HCl}$ (hydrochloric acid)
- $\ce{KNO3}$ (potassium nitrate, a nitrate salt)
- $\ce{Cu}$ (copper)

The reaction should produce nitrogen dioxide ($\ce{NO2}$).

The chemical equation should look like this:

$$
\ce{HCl + KNO3 + Cu -> NO2}
$$

But I'm clearly missing something. Can anybody help me equalize and complete this equation?

Comment: What kind of reaction is this? Are you putting acid into solution? I assume you don't know the other products and that is what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't really know what is the reaction type. No I'm not putting acid into solution, I'm producing nitric acid using a  nitrate salt, copper and hydrochloric acid, I don't know the products yeah that's it

Comment: Looks right to me. It is strongly encouraged on Chemistry.SE to answer your own question in a formal answer rather than an edit. This will help others to find the right answer if they have a similar question. You could also possibly earn the Self-Lerner badge! Just show any work that you did to get the right equation. Also you should use the proper formatting, which you can read more about [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here). It's really not that difficult. I will also edit your question so you have another example.

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me with the formatting ! I didn't know that I can answer my own question, I'll try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologizes, I found the answer. The full equation is :
$$\ce{Cu + 4KNO3 + 4HCl -> Cu(NO3)2 + 2NO2 + 4KCl + 2H2O}$$
(I'll detail this later)

Comment: Why not CuCl2 and KNO3, more likely because chloride is a better complexant than nitrate. Write out the ionic equation.

Comment: What happens if all the nitrate is reacted? balance the equation then. The equation is bogus.

Answer (score 0):

Copper reacts in more concentrated nitric acid to give NO2 and possibly some NO depending on concentration.  What happens in the above scenario depends on the concentrations of H+, equal at first to Cl-, Cl-, and NO3-; K+ balances the charge. If the amount of hydrochloric acid is enough, the process makes a mild aqua regia. Such solutions use the complexing ability of chloride to facilitate oxidation by nitrate. [with also the possible formation of Cl2]

In nitric acid:  Cu + 2NO3- + 4H+ = Cu++ + 2NO2 + 2H2O

With sufficient chloride ion: Cu + 2NO3- +4H+ + Cl- = CuCl+ + 2NO2 + 2H2O

An ultraviolet-visible spectrum should define what is going on. [Possibly just observing the solution would be sufficient.]